# Should a Federal Tax Id be encrypted in a database?

Tags: database, security, encryption

My first inclination is to say yes, since it's essentially a corporation's SSN which I would encrypt. However, I'm not sure whether SOX or and Federal guidelines actually require it to be encrypted. Anyone know for sure?

Comment: Free legal advice is worth every cent you pay. Ask a lawyer.

Comment: In the title you ask "Should" and in the text you say "require".  Which are you asking? They're very different questions.

Comment: Ask a manager. An important part of their job is to assess risks on behalf of your organization. How they perform their assessment is up to them. Also note you can look them up for a fee: http://www.feinsearch.com/

Comment: It is not at all like a SSN for things that matter. It won't, for example, help you get credit in the name of the corporation. Plus the corporation gives that number out to *every* one of its employees on its W2 forms.

Answer (score 3):

My rule of thumb: **if you have to ask, the answer is probably yes**

But I agree with @Adam, you should ask a lawyer about legal matters.

Answer (score 1):

Considering that EIN's are generally public information - public companies put them on their 10-K and private companies usually include them on their D&B, it's probably not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

After further research, it appears that there is no specific requirement that a Tax ID (or SSN for that matter) be encrypted in the data layer, however, they need to be masked when presented to users.